# Overlay/docking effect of the VS2013 find and replace control using WPF

Tags: wpf

How can I achieve the overlay/docking effect of the find and replace control on the top right hand corner of the text editor using WPF?

[image: vs2013 find and replace]

Thanks

Comment: What did you try, what was your specific problem with what you did?

Comment: I have tried a regular find and replace non-modal window. The problem is that I am unsure where to start in order to overlay it and dock it to the top right hand corner of a textbox.

Comment: Use a container control that allows free placement and put both controls in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place both the `TextBox` and the find and replace control inside the same `Grid` control and align the find and replace control to place it in the top right corner. Also make sure that you put the control in the XAML after the `TextBox` so that it will be rendered on top of it:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" />
    <local:FindControl HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                       Width="230" Height="20" />
</Grid>
```

In my example `FindControl` is a custom control containg the find and replace functionality.